# Downloaded MMS stream has very long duration

Tags: avconv, stream

I have successfully downloaded a one minute long stream:

```
$ mimms -t 1 mms://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3 out.asf
mms://stream.polskieradio.pl/program3 => out.asf
744.45 kB / ∞ B (12.00 kB/s, ∞ s remaining)        
Download stopped after user-specified timeout.

$ avprobe out.asf 2>&1 | grep Duration
  Duration: 00:00:59.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 99 kb/s
```

Then I just coppied audio stream to another file:

```
$ avconv -i out.asf -c:a copy out2.asf
avconv version 9.16-6:9.16-0ubuntu0.14.04.1, Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the Libav developers
  built on Aug 10 2014 18:16:02 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
[asf @ 0x14af020] max_analyze_duration reached
[asf @ 0x14af020] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : stereo
Input #0, asf, from 'out.asf':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.0.7601.17514
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 0
  Duration: 00:00:59.55, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 99 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: wmav2, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s
    Stream #0.1(eng): Data: [0][0][0][0] / 0x0000, 4 kb/s
Output #0, asf, to 'out2.asf':
  Metadata:
    WMFSDKVersion   : 12.0.7601.17514
    WMFSDKNeeded    : 0.0.0.0000
    IsVBR           : 0
    WM/EncodingSettings: Lavf54.20.4
    Stream #0.0(eng): Audio: wmav2, 48000 Hz, stereo, 96 kb/s
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
size=    1119kB time=1810474.72 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
video:0kB audio:717kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead 56.223058%
```

And this happens:

```
$ avprobe out2.asf 2>&1 | grep Duration
  Duration: 502:54:34.71, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 0 kb/s
```

Is there any way to make it back to 1 minute as it should be?

Comment: Hello. Please consider filing the bug, so that this issue can be fixed. You can follow the the steps outlined here. Please don't forget to upload the files in question.

Comment: Could you also post another avprobe without the grep? Does it also say about estimating the duration from the bitrate? If so what does it report the bitrate to be and what is the size of the file?

Answer (score -1):

Not sure why it matters - you have the orig. file.

But try using FFmpeg instead, should work better. A standalone binary can be had here to test with. Choose either the git master or release, download, extract & run ffmpeg from extracted folder

http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Or build your own - https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu

Comment: If you recommend a piece of software that had the same base before the split, you probably should provide explanation as to why you believe that this bug doesn't exist in your particular version.

Comment: Just try it, it's not to me to debug Libav's issues, could care less. FFmpeg works fine in this regard & many others

Comment: "it's not to me to debug Libav's issues, could care less". So by posting on the question about debugging Libav issues you are just trolling?